# How to convert text in textblock from upper to lower case using checkbox click?

Tags: windows, windows-phone

How to convert textblock text from upper to lower in main page when checkbox is clicked in another sample page? I am using c# which is for Windows Phone Apps

Comment: Please add more information about what language you use, and more about the context!

Answer (score 2):

It'd be like this in C#:

```
 private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
            label1.Text = label1.Text.ToLower();
        else
            label1.Text = label1.Text.ToUpper();
    }
```

where checkBox1 is your checkbox and label1 is name of your text field.
If you want to access it from another page and there are a bunch of things you'd like to access like that, I'd recommend creating a static class with references to these items so you can access them from anywhere.